# how to deal with foreign keys with fixed values (on a db-table-basis)

Tags: mysql, schema

I have a **control table** that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_control` (
  `tm_db_tbl` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tm_key` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  /* a bunch of other fields here */
  PRIMARY KEY (`tm_db_tbl`,`tm_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

From the perspective of my other tables, when I want to join on this control table, I join on the `tm_key` in my table along with a string literal designating my database and table against the `tm_db_tbl` field above.  With the client table below, I would join `WHERE ct.tm_db_tbl='my_db.some_client_table' AND ct.tm_key=sct.tm_key`.

```
CREATE TABLE `some_client_table` (
  `tm_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  /* a bunch of other fields here */
  PRIMARY KEY (`tm_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is a tiny bit of optimization so I don't have a `tm_db_tbl` column in my client table with all the same values.  *The relationship here is many-client-tables-to-one-control-table.*

But now, I run into a bit of a problem when I want to define a `foreign key` on my client table because the corresponding `tm_db_tbl` is a string-literal.

Should I just bite-the-bullet and add `tm_db_tbl` filled all with the same value to my table or is there a better way around this problem?

If it makes any difference, I am using mysql.

Comment: No time for a full answer now, but if you buy the bullet, convert the `varchar(64)` to an `int` (or even better `smallint`). I don't suppose you have more than 64K tables in there and 2 bytes vs 64 in an index is always good deal.

Comment: `foreign key` doesn't make much sense for MyISAM engine...

Comment: @a1ex07 +1 ty - I will change that to InnoDB

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is that you can't define a foreign key constraint that uses anything other than just the columns in the primary key that you are referencing.

One of the ways that people sometimes use to consolidate keys across multiple tables is to use a GUID as the primary key.  If the `tm_key` in each of your tables was a GUID then you could impose the foreign key using declarative referential integrity without carrying the `tm_db_tbl` column in your `some_client_table`.

Failing that, your options are:

1. Forego declarative referential integrity and just ensure that you
   have indexes that make your joins efficient.
2. Impose referential integrity procedurally.
3. Take ypercube's suggestion and find a more
   efficient way to represent `some_client_table.tb_db_tbl`.